# How can I easily find a line of text which is on my website on the code in my server?

Tags: linux, code, linux-server

There is a line of text on my website which I would like to edit. Is there an easy way for me find/locate the folder and or sub folder where that line of text is located in the code on my server so I can go there, locate that line of text and edit it? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have SSH access, you can use `grep`:

```
grep -r "text you're looking for" /path/of/your/website
```

You can add the `-i` flag for case insensitive search.

You can add `-n` to get the line number of that occurrence.

Comment: If it's a large amount of text add --color to highlight the string, -n option to print out line numbers, and -l (the lower case letter "L") to print the file name. I typically end up forming this command as `grep -lin 'something' *`